# User has_many :users, :through => :friends - how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

This is my code:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  has_many :friends
  has_many :users, :through => :friends
  #...
end
```

When I now start adding users by...

```
user.users << user2
user.save
```

Only the user_id of friend is filled, friend_id is null.

Any help?

Yours,
Joern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `:source` attribute to your `has_many through` association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :friends
 has_many :users, :source => :friend, :through => :friends
end
```

Now the following calls will work.

```
u1.users << u2    
u.friends.last
# will print #<Friend id: 1, user_id: 1, friend_id: 4>
```

**Notes:**

1. Rails auto saves the associations.You need to call `save` only if the user model is new.
2. You probably should rename the association to something more explicit. E.g: `friend_users` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try: [Railscasts - Self-Referential Associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association). Generally has very good tutorials on all topics listed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need delete the belongs_to :user in your Friend model