# ActiveRecord: Including associations on a group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I really like ActiveRecord, but sometimes I find these (relatively) complicated queries challenging and I don't know how to ask for help.

Here's my method:

```
  def self.get_top_victims_for_player(player, count=10)
    top_victims = player
                  .kills
                  .group(:victim)
                  .order('count_id DESC')
                  .limit(count)
                  .count(:id)

    formatted = top_victims.map do |player, count|
      { "#{player.names.first.name} (#{player.steam_id})" => count}
    end.reduce({}, :merge)

    { type: "list", data: formatted }
  end
```

The goal is to get a Top-10 list of the victims of the provided player's kills.

This line:
`{ "#{player.names.first.name} (#{player.steam_id})" => count}`
creates many queries to retrieve the associated `Names` for each player. I feel like if I was able to eager-load this `Name` association, I could retrieve the first `Name` for each player in one query.

Here're the logs when the method is run:

```
D, [2017-12-18T23:49:11.324957 #26877] DEBUG -- :   Player Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "players".* FROM "players" WHERE "players"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 304], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-12-18T23:49:11.332907 #26877] DEBUG -- :    (5.2ms)  SELECT  COUNT("kills"."id") AS count_id, "kills"."victim_id" AS kills_victim_id FROM "kills" WHERE "kills"."player_id" = $1 GROUP BY "kills"."victim_id" ORDER BY count_id DESC LIMIT $2  [["player_id", 304], ["LIMIT", 10]]
D, [2017-12-18T23:49:11.335472 #26877] DEBUG -- :   Player Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "players".* FROM "players" WHERE "players"."id" IN (735, 96, 98, 893, 335, 213, 2801, 268, 1391, 3108)
D, [2017-12-18T23:49:11.338581 #26877] DEBUG -- :   Name Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "names".* FROM "names" WHERE "names"."player_id" = $1 ORDER BY "names"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["player_id", 735], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-12-18T23:49:11.341112 #26877] DEBUG -- :   Name Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "names".* FROM "names" WHERE "names"."player_id" = $1 ORDER BY "names"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["player_id", 96], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-12-18T23:49:11.343411 #26877] DEBUG -- :   Name Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "names".* FROM "names" WHERE "names"."player_id" = $1 ORDER BY "names"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["player_id", 98], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-12-18T23:49:11.345129 #26877] DEBUG -- :   Name Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "names".* FROM "names" WHERE "names"."player_id" = $1 ORDER BY "names"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["player_id", 893], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-12-18T23:49:11.346893 #26877] DEBUG -- :   Name Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "names".* FROM "names" WHERE "names"."player_id" = $1 ORDER BY "names"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["player_id", 335], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-12-18T23:49:11.348842 #26877] DEBUG -- :   Name Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "names".* FROM "names" WHERE "names"."player_id" = $1 ORDER BY "names"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["player_id", 213], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-12-18T23:49:11.351487 #26877] DEBUG -- :   Name Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "names".* FROM "names" WHERE "names"."player_id" = $1 ORDER BY "names"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["player_id", 2801], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-12-18T23:49:11.354888 #26877] DEBUG -- :   Name Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "names".* FROM "names" WHERE "names"."player_id" = $1 ORDER BY "names"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["player_id", 268], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-12-18T23:49:11.357178 #26877] DEBUG -- :   Name Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "names".* FROM "names" WHERE "names"."player_id" = $1 ORDER BY "names"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["player_id", 1391], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-12-18T23:49:11.358084 #26877] DEBUG -- :   Name Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "names".* FROM "names" WHERE "names"."player_id" = $1 ORDER BY "names"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["player_id", 3108], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Association info:

- `Player has_many :kills`
- `Player has_many :names`
- `Kill belongs_to :player`
- `Kill belongs_to :victim, :class_name => 'Player', foreign_key: 'victim_id'`
- `Name belongs_to :player`

How can I optimize this method?

(Sidenote: Where can I learn more about this? What resources should I use when I have a question similar to this?)

Comment: Can you add the log when calling this method?

Comment: I added the method logs, thanks.

Comment: Try `player.include(:names).kills...`

Comment: if you want to eager load the records then try something like: `Player.includes(:kills, :names).where(id: self.id)` and so on..I am not sure what else could be the issue.

Comment: You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43696520/5883753) answer to learn more about **eager loading**.

Comment: which table column does `count_id` belong to?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, this throws an error as `player` is an instance of `Player`. 

`NoMethodError - undefined method 'include' for #<Player id: 304">`

Comment: @Abhinay This returned an error because `.kills` can't be run on a `.where` relation collection. If I do a `.where(id: player.id).first` (or `.find(player.id)`), the query actually ends up being slower.

Comment: @WasifHossain I believe `count_id` is a SQL-y thing. It's not actually a field on any of my models. I should read up on this though.

Comment: would you pls elaborate the criteria on which to get the Top-10 list of the victims for a particular player?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create another model with a hmt relationship that tallies new kills as they come in? New model:
`UserKilledPlayers`:
`belongs_to :user`

In user model:

```
has_many :user_killed_players     
has_many :killed_players, source: :user_killed_players, through: :users_killed_players
```

Your table would be something like:
user_killed_players

```
user_id  | killed_players_id |  count
```

Make a method that `++` on the `count` every time a user kills another user. Then it would just be an easy one query

`UserKilledPlayer.where(user_id: current_user).order('max(count) DESC')`

More details on associating users to users with has many through: 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404246/user-has-many-users-through-friends-how)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that retrieves the data in one query:

```
def self.get_top_victims_for_player(player_id, count=10)
  sql_string = <<-EOS
with first_names as 
( select distinct on (player_id) player_id, name 
from names 
order by player_id, id ) 
select players.steam_id, first_names.name, count(kills.id) 
from kills 
join first_names on kills.victim_id = first_names.player_id 
join players on kills.victim_id = players.id 
where kills.player_id = #{player_id} 
group by kills.victim_id, first_names.name, players.steam_id 
order by count(kills.id) desc 
limit #{count}
  EOS
  res = connection.execute(sql_string)
  res.map {|h| {"#{h['name']} (#{h['steam_id']})" => h["count"]}  }
end
```

Sample run using some local data:

```
>> Player.get_top_victims_for_player(1)
   (1.0ms)      with first_names as 
      ( select distinct on (player_id) player_id, name 
      from names 
      order by player_id, id ) 
    select players.steam_id, first_names.name, count(kills.id) 
    from kills 
    join first_names on kills.victim_id = first_names.player_id 
    join players on kills.victim_id = players.id 
    where kills.player_id = 1 
    group by kills.victim_id, first_names.name, players.steam_id 
    order by count(kills.id) desc 
    limit 10

=> [{"name2 (2)"=>5}, {"name3 (3)"=>3}, {"name4 (4)"=>2}]
```

Downsides are that it's PostgreSQL-specific due to CTE and DISTINCT ON, and also it has lots of raw SQL.  Probably it could be made more Active Record-ish with a bit of work though.